# If $\mu$ is a finite measure and $ν$ is a signed measure with $|\nu|\le C\mu$, are we able to show $\left|\frac{{\rm d}ν}{{\rm d}\mu}\right|\le C$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, reference-request, signed-measures

Let

- $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\mu)$ be a finite measure space
- $\nu$ be a signed measure on $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ with $$|\nu(A)|\le C\mu(A)\;\;\;\text{for all }A\in\mathcal A\tag1$$ for some $C\ge0$

Note that $(1)$ implies $\nu\ll\mu$ and hence $$\nu(A)=\int_Af\:{\rm d}\mu\;\;\;\text{for all }A\in\mathcal A\tag2$$ for some $f\in L^1(\mu)$.

> I want to show that $$|f|\le C\;\;\;\mu\text{-almost everywhere}\tag3\;.$$ How can we do that?

Comment: Let $A_n=\{f> C+1/n\}$. Then $C\mu(A_n)\geq \nu(A_n)=\int_{A_n}fd\mu\geq (C+1/n)\mu(A_n)$. Therefore $\mu(A_n)=0$ Do a similar job for $B_n=\{f<-C-1/n\}$ and take union of all $A_n$ and $B_n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: For any simple function $g$ with $\|g\|_{L^{1}}\leq 1$, one shows that
\begin{align*}
\left|\int fgd\mu\right|\leq C,
\end{align*}
then by letting $f_{n}=f\chi_{E_{n}}$, $E_{n}=\{|x|\leq n, |f(x)|\leq n\}$, one shows that $\|f_{n}\|_{\infty}\leq C$ and $\|f\|_{\infty}=\lim_{n}\|f_{n}\|_{\infty}\leq C$.

Here the converse Holder's inequality/theorem is used.